# Get objects from collection and ignore excluded collections inside

Tags: python, collections

I need to get list of mesh objects in collection and ignore excluded collections inside:

[image]
[image]

```
import bpy

all_visible_meshes = []

for obj in bpy.data.collections["Collection"].all_objects:
        if obj.type == "MESH" and obj.hide_viewport == False:
            all_visible_meshes.append(obj)

print(all_visible_meshes)
```

Result: `[bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Sphere']]`

I need only `[bpy.data.objects['Cube']]`

Comment: Hello ! Have you explored [bpy.context.selectable_objects](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selectable_objects) ? eg `if obj not in bpy.context.selectable_objects: continue`

Comment: Hello. Edited: Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import bpy

collection_objects = set(bpy.data.collections["Collection"].all_objects)
visible_objects = set(bpy.context.visible_objects)
visible_objects_in_collection = collection_objects.intersection(visible_objects)
print(visible_objects_in_collection)
```

Be advised that it will create a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) so member access is not deterministic. You can convert it to a list.

```
visible_objects_in_collection = list(visible_objects_in_collection)
print(visible_objects_in_collection)
```

[Link to the docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.context.html#bpy.context.selectable_objects)